# Using SSH Keys in Transmit to connect via SFTP

Tags: macos, sftp

I'm using Transmit to connect via SFTP to a server. I know that the public key is properly uploaded etc. because I can connect via SSH on the command line.

For some reason I can't connect with SFTP in Transmit. My keys are in the default location (`~/.ssh`) so I can't imagine Transmit is having a hard time finding them.

Comment: SFTP is an SSH protocol extension. The GUI has nothing to do with the protocols.

Comment: While Transmit uses keys in `.ssh` automatically, have you tried specifying one explicitly by editing the connection and clicking on the key icon, then selecting your keyfile? Press `Cmd-Shift-.` in the file dialog to show hidden files and folders, such as `.ssh/`

Comment: @daniel - yes I did; turns out it was a bug verified by transmit tech support; files with a . in the name are not read properly, my keys were named things like 'my_key_name.pub'

Comment: Please post that as an answer and click the checkmark to accept it once possible. This'll mark the question resolved in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent an email to the makers of transmit to get technical support and it was confirmed that I had encountered a bug. It seems a key with a `.` in the name will not be recognized by the software -- it can not be loaded up either manually or automatically.

Renaming my keys to remove the `.` solved the problem.